# How to disable Unknown Tracker Alerts for specific trackers?

Tags: security, notifications

Android warns you of unknown trackers following you without their owners.  EG Apple Airtags and Life360 Tiles. This can warn you if someone has planted a tracker on you or your property without your knowledge.

If you put an Airtag or a Tile in a family car, (a very cheap Lojack) with everyone's knowledge of course, then anyone who drives or rides in the car with an Android gets Unknown Tracker warnings constantly.   It seems you can turn off these warnings entirely but that's undesirable.  Can you turn them off for specific trackers, namely ones you are aware of and don't want to be warned about?

Comment: Moderators -- The "security" tag is probably not right.  I don't have the rep to create a tag but I suggest "Safety" or "unknown-trackers".

Comment: These trackers AFAIK run on Bluetooth. So, if you can identify that tracker using some app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cac.bluetoothmanager), you should be able to turn it off and preventing alert? //I haven't used a tracker so this is a guess

Comment: @beeshyams there are techniques to find and disable unknown trackers.  Mainly, remove the battery.  But that's not my objective.  A tracker is tied to exactly one phone.  If you have one in a car, other phones in the family generate stalker alerts.  My objective is to disable those alerts, but not for all trackers, only for known safe ones.